# change bool variable with radio button

Tags: javascript, html, arduino, webserver

i have a ESP32 async webserver which i want to use to control some variables.

For this problem radio buttons seem a good idea, since they look nice and i have a lot of (bool) variables, so i think that simple input forms wouldnt look nice.

Since i have no real experience with javascript i wanted to get some support instead of trying countless times and then asking here for some help. Just know that i program everything in Arduino IDE.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>ESP Input Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <h4>Show Peaks:</h4>
  <form action="/get" class="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="on" name="show_peaks" value="on">
    <label for="on">On</label>
    <input type="radio" id="off" name="show_peaks" value="off">
    <label for="off">Off</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="RadioValidator()">
  </form>

   <script>

  function RadioValidator() {
      if(document.getElementById('on').checked) {
        show_peaks = true;  
      }
      else if(document.getElementById('off').checked) {
        show_peaks = false; 
      }
    }

  </script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

This javascript is very basic and i might not use the exact same line but is something like that possible? Should i do something different?

Every help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: JavaScript executes on the client, not the server.

Comment: You don't need the JavaScript. The submit button will send the button value to the server, it can then update its variable.

Comment: But if you don't want to reload the page, you can use AJAX.

Comment: I use this part of the code on an ESP32 which is also the webserver. How would i use AJAX? I am just now reading something about it

Comment: Even if the browser and server are on the same machine, they're separate processes, they don't share the same JavaScript variables.

Comment: And how would i transfer a JavaScript variable so i can use it in my Main-Code? Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Use `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest`, and send the variable as the body of the request, perhaps converting it to JSON if necessary. Tutorials on AJAX will provide the details, I can't teach you the details here.